# How do I make Java Hashtable.containsKey to work for Array?

Tags: java, hashtable

Sorry to ask this question but i am new to Java.

```
Hashtable<byte[],byte[]> map = new Hashtable<byte[],byte[]>();
byte[] temp = {1, -1, 0};
map.put(temp, temp);
byte[] temp2 = {1, -1, 0};;
System.err.println(map.containsKey(temp2));
```

does NOT work with .containsKey (as the printed result is "False")

```
Hashtable<Integer,Integer> mapint = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
int i = 5;
mapint.put(i, i);
int j = 5;
System.err.println(mapint.containsKey(j));
```

works (the printed result is "True")

I understand it has something to do with object reference, but could not reach any solution after searching...

Is there anyway I can use Hashtable to find key with Array type? I just want to test if a specific array is in Hashtable as a key...

Any hits would be great. Thank!!!

Comment: For your specific issue, you can wrap the array with a `ByteBuffer`, `map.put(ByteBuffer.wrap(temp), temp);`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use arrays as keys in a `HashTable/HashMap`, since they don't override the default implementation of `Object`'s `equals`, which means `temp.equals(temp2)` if and only if `temp==temp2`, which is not true in your case.

You can use a `Set<Byte>` or `List<Byte>` instead of a `byte[]` for your key.

For example :

```
Hashtable<List<Byte>,Byte[]> map = new Hashtable<List<Byte>,Byte[]>();
Byte[] temp = {1, -1, 0};
map.put(Arrays.asList(temp), temp);
Byte[] temp2 = {1, -1, 0};;
System.err.println(map.containsKey(Arrays.asList(temp2)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! In this case, i need to use alternative method, one naive methid I can think of is to convert array into String, but that seems dumb... Is there anyway to go around this?

Comment: @Jack See my example. BTW, why do you use a HashTable if the key and the value are the same? You can use a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I works! I will study the use of     Set<Byte> or     List<Byte>...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, actually Key and Value are not the same, they are just quick test for this examle :-)

Comment: Thank you again for the solution!

Comment: @Jack if the solution helps can you mark answer as accepted by clicking check sign next to answer

Comment: `ByteBuffer` is probably more efficient than `List<Byte>`; it does the right thing with hashing and equals without the boxing overhead for each individual byte.